How to create differential equations that follow a certain shape?
When it comes to non-differential equations, it is well known how to create functions of certain shapes.
For example, if I want a function to oscillate, I could use trigonometric functions. If I want a function to have exponential decay, I could use logarithms.
I recently posted a question about differential equations (Applying the Euler Method to problems in Epidemiology). The differential equations I am dealing with look like this:
$$ \frac{dS}{dt} = -\beta SI $$
$$ \frac{dI}{dt} = \beta SI - \gamma I $$
$$ \frac{dR}{dt} = \gamma I $$
The plot looks like this (approximated using Euler Method for some specific constant values):

I have the following question: Without plotting this system, I would have no idea how this would look. Suppose I wanted to make a system of differential that looked a certain way, e.g. the red curve to increase slower, or the green curve to look like the red curve (i.e. go up and down).
How is it possible to know how a system of differential equations will look like without plotting it? Or if I want to make a system of differential equations to look a certain way, how can we do this?

ti;dr The answer that follows is in lieu of simply closing the question as much too general for an answer.
For any particular problem your intuition guides how you construct a model.
In this case you'd expect the pictured curves for the susceptibles, starting near the whole population, decreasing rapidly, leveling off to $0$ when pretty much everyone has recovered. The recovered curve has the opposite behavior. Infecteds start at $0$, peak, then level off at $0$. The differential equations you write down capture what the rates of change of the three variables are proportional to. When you solve them you get the logistic curves you expect.
If you had three variables (red, green and yellow) and you thought in your context that the green curve should look like the red curve you would write a similar differential equation for it - one that made sense in your application. The precise shape of that equation would depend on assumptions you make in your model. Then you would solve the system of differential equations to confirm your intuition.
